# Hiding parts of a scrollbar using only CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide specific parts of a scrollbar. My exact requirement is to hide the `scrollbar-track-piece`, but have the actual `srcollbar-thumb` visible. (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/)

While I'm pretty sure this is not possible, I'm just posting this question here in case I am wrong.

I've tried `pointer-events: none`, setting `display: none` and modifying the `z-index`, but neither seem to be working. I'd prefer not using JavaScript, if possible.

Having it work only in Chrome is good enough for me. (Trying this in Electron)

Thanks in advance!

Use case:
I'm trying to make a half-native, half-custom scrollbar, wherein you can click and drag on the `scrollbar-thumb` to make it behave like scrollbars do, but clicking on the `scrollbar-track-piece`, isn't possible.
I made a little thing:
[image]

Comment: You might want to include the browsers you wish for this to work in, as support for UI styling is still vastly different between browsers.

Comment: Just Chrome is enough. I'll edit the question. Thanks!

Comment: I just checked the Chrome inspector, and I don't think Chrome has any CSS that affects scrollbars.

Comment: @raphael75 You mean this is an OS level thing? :/

Comment: It appears that way. :( As I'm sure you know,this can be achieved using javascript, but I know you were trying to avoid that.

Comment: Yeah, I feel uncomfortable using JS for something as basic as scrolling, because there will always be ways people use scrollbars that I don't even realize, hence will leave out.

Comment: You may hide the scrollbar track by various ways, but it seems clickable anyway, at least on my chrome version. So JS looks only option here

Comment: You could try playing with overflow and setting widths and heights on the box.

Comment: So you're not trying to _hide_ the scrollbar partially, only _disable_ it, right? I'm not sure how that fits in with allowing people to use scrollbars in ways you can't think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in chrome easily enough using these vendor specific selectors. I'm not sure all browsers support this, but chrome does.

```
   ::-webkit-scrollbar-track { display: none; cursor: none; pointer-events: none }
```

You can find all the info you need about css styling of the scroll bar here:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/

However if you really want to create a custom scroll bar that works with all browsers you will need javascript. For now...